# How to construct destination type via constructor while using mappers for each parameter?

Tags: automapper

Is there a way to map through a constructor while using a mappers for each of the parameters. For example if I have a dto

```cs
   public class CreateBid
   {
      public int ClientId { get; set; }
      public int RegulatoryBodyId {get;set;}
      public string Descripption {get;set;
    }
```

and command

```
   public class CreateBidCommand
   {
      public CreateBidCommand(Client client, 
             RegulatoryBody regulatoryBody, string description)
      {
           Client = client;
           RegulatoryBody = regulatoryBody;
           Description = description;
      }

      public Client Client {get;}
      public RegulatoryBody RegulatoryBody {get;}
      public string Description {get;}
  }
```

and I have setup automapping based on the suffix so that for example
  RegulatoryBodyId is mapped to instance RegualtoryBody,

I have all working if I make properties on my command public, which is not what I want.

What I want is for automapper to use constructor, and see that on source I have ClientId, in constructor I have a instance of Client, so use map to map int=>typeInstance. For all other members that are not in constructor use property mapping. Is this possible?

Just to re-iterate following works

```
_mapper.Map<int,Client>(112313);
```

or

```
_mapper.Map<string,SomeType>("someCode");
```

What I want is to apply this to every matching member in the constructor, based on the suffixes defined in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

As of now this is not supported. I opened an issue in GH #1253/